# Image resizing php code

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have this php code that displays the first image from a post on my main page. The images sizes seem to be random. I would like to make them all the same size.

You can see the three images at the bottom of the page:http://www.wha2wear.com/
And this is the code:

```
<div class="blog">
    <h2><span>Sneak peak</span></h2>
    <ul>
<?php query_posts('orderby=comment_count&posts_per_page=6'); if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<li>
<h3 class="short_title"><a title="Post: <?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo ShortTitle(get_the_title()); ?> </a></h3>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php getImage('1'); ?></a>



<?php endwhile; ?></li>
<?php else : ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts were found.</p>
<?php endif; ?>


    </ul>


    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please show your `getImage` function

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, just entered it correctly, thanks!

Comment: You're still now showing your `getImage` function

Answer (score 3):

Using `HTML`, you would need to use `CSS` to resize an image. You could use:

`<img src="/page-to-image" style="width:100px; hight:200px" />`

Comment: hello, thank you. How do I set the correct image source? for it to be the first image of each post..in the function it's getImage('1');

Comment: @Candice you would have to `echo` the code I showed you before, and set the image path to a variable and the `src` would be
`src="$variable"`

Comment: @Candice You created the `getImage` function, and we don't know what it does, because you're not showing us the code body.  Please, *please*, *please* show us the code.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually I didn't create it, I'm just tampering with it lol...I'm not sure what you mean by the code body, this php function is in the home-page.php it retrieves the first image from a post and there's also a timthumb.php ...sorry for being so clueless I'm still learning